# Interop DLL returning member not found

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll, interop

OK, this is a shot in the dark as I'm at my wits end.  I have two third-party DLLs that work great in VB6, but not so much in VB.NET or C#.

In VB6, the below works just fine:

```
Dim oApplication As Object
Dim oSession As Object
Dim vRetCode As Variant

Set oApplication = CreateObject("OAPPLICA.OAPPLICA")
Set oSession = CreateObject("OSESSION.OSESSION")

oApplication.PROGRAMDRIVE = "\\dev\data\"
oApplication.WORKAREADRIVE = "\\dev\data\workarea\"
oApplication.DATADRIVE = "\\dev\data\"
oApplication.IMAGEDRIVE = "\\dev\data\image\"

oSession.MYAPPLICATION = oApplication
vRetCode = oSession.LOGIN("USER1", "PASSWORD1") 'Returns zero if successful

MsgBox (vRetCode)
```

When I run this exact same set of code in VB.NET I get "Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))" on the "oSession.MYAPPLICATION = oApplication" line.

I've tried doing early binding as well in both VB.NET and C#, but eventually end up with the same error on a different line.  I get the same error for the below on the "oApplication.set_PROGRAMDRIVE("\\dev\lifepro\data\");" line.

```
private OAPPLICA.OAPPLICA oApplication = new OAPPLICA.OAPPLICA();
private OSESSION.OSESSION oSession = new OSESSION.OSESSION();
Int64 iReturnCode;

oApplication.set_PROGRAMDRIVE("\\\\dev\\data\\");
oApplication.set_WORKAREADRIVE("\\\\dev\\data\\workarea\\");
oApplication.set_DATADRIVE("\\\\dev\\data\\");
oApplication.set_IMAGEDRIVE("\\\\dev\\data\\image");

m_oSession.set_MYAPPLICATION(m_oApplication);
iReturnCode = Convert.ToInt64(m_oSession.LOGIN("USER1", "PASSWORD1"));
```

As stated earlier, the two DLLs (OAPPLICA.dll and OSESSION.dll) are third-party and allow an entry point into a third-party legacy system.  Since it's legacy I don't have access to the third-party anymore, I've just been tasked with trying to prototype converting an existing Windows VB6 application into an .NET web application.  My hunch is .NET is having an issue interpreting the interop DLL for the two COM objects, but I have been unable to find anything to point me in a direction.

Comment: How did you add the two dll's to your project? Rightclick, "Add Reference" and "COM" tab?

Comment: The two DLLs were added exactly how you described.

Comment: Does the method `.set_Application` come up in intellisense, the reason I ask is because the error message is Member Not Found... and the VB6 code doesn't use the .set_Application `method`, it assigns to the MYAPPLICATION `Property`.

Comment: Yes, the .set_Application came up in intellisense.  The original property method didn't come up like it did in VB6, and since I was trying to set the application property I figured this was how the interop DLL interpreted that functionality.

Comment: @Chris, do you have .Net Reflector? If not, check this out. http://27.am/posts/how-to-download-net-reflector-6-for-free . Once you have it we can take a look at the interop assembly and maybe see why those methods are not found.

Comment: Getting a DISP_E error on an early bound property/method call defies any reasonable explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it.  For some reason .NET interprets the properties as read-only at run-time (for both C# an VB.NET and for both web and windows), even though there are get and set options at design-time.  VB6 interprets the properties as get and set at both run-time and design-time, so you can imagine my confusion.  I've never come across anything like this before.  Anyway, I started out putting a VB6 wrapper around the third-party DLLs, and then had .NET reference the VB6 wrapper DLL.  Worked great and allowed me to continue development, but still wanted to eliminate the extra VB6 layer.  One of our COBOL developers was eventually able to mimic/rewrite the legacy DLLs.  I hate losing time on crap like this, but I'm glad it's done.

Comment: what is the meaning of VB6 wrapper?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that this code would run fine in a WinForms app, have you tried that?

VB6, and most COM components designed for use with VB6, are going to require you to run on an STA thread to work properly.  Your web code is likely running on at MTA thread.

Comment: Yep, tried that.  I switched over to a WinForms app just to see if I could get something to work and I got the same issue.

Comment: One thing ruled out at least.  I'd stick with dedugging via the WinApp though just so you are battling only one thing at a time.

Comment: I've gotten a bit further.  I recreated everything in a Windows XP (32-bit)/VS2010 environment and it works fine.  So, in a Windows 7 (64-bit)/VS2010 environment I get the discussed behavior.  The 64-bit Windows environment doesn't like the registered COM DLL for some reason.  Going to do some more research, but I'll probably end up opening a Microsoft support ticket.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize you were 64 bit.  Compile your .Net as x86 instead of Any

Comment: What are you using to register the COM components with?  Try using the version in C:\Windows\SysWOW64.  Double check the regitry entries for the COM component on the working system and compare to the non working system.  And finally, use ProcessMonitor as the code execute to see if is actually reading the correct reg keys and locating the COM dlls.

Comment: Yep, tried registering versions from SysWOW64 and System32.  I got it to somewhat "work" by copying the DLL to the SysWOW64 directory, registering it, and then using late binding.  Can't get it to work using early binding still, but I've made some progress.  This thing is killing me!

Comment: Never could figure this out so had to do a bit of a hack job.  We decided to wrap the legacy DLL inside a VB6 interface DLL.  VB.NET and C# then have no issue interpreting the VB6 DLL.  I've got a ticket into Microsoft as well as NetCOBOL (the legacy DLL was written in Fujitsu NetCOBOL for Windows).  I don't have high hopes for either one, but it's "working" with the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

If @tcarvin is correct, and he probably is, you can force an ASP.net app to be STA by using an "AspCompat=true" page directive - [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwk9h2kb.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwk9h2kb.aspx)